# Why there is an infinite recursion when function parameter is not defined as const reference?

Tags: c++, recursion, c++17

I am having troubles understanding what might be causing the infinite recursion. There are two points that play a role in my problem

1. Depending on the place of definition of the global functions
2. Whether we mark the parameter as const-ref of the second function (either global or class member)

Here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>
#include <vector>

using dataType = int;
using dataTypeReturn = float;
//#define ENABLE_AFTER  // For global fncs causes inf recursion
#define CONST_REF_FUNCTION  // Causes expected behavior when !ENABLED_AFTER
#define CONST_REF_CLASS     // Causes expected behavior

#ifndef ENABLE_AFTER
#ifdef CONST_REF_FUNCTION
// Causes expected behavior
std::vector<dataTypeReturn> foo(const dataType& bar){
#else
std::vector<dataTypeReturn> foo(dataType& bar){
#endif
    std::cout << "foo(const dataType& bar)" << std::endl;
    return std::vector<dataTypeReturn>(10, dataTypeReturn{});
}
#endif

std::vector<dataTypeReturn> foo(const std::optional<dataType>& bar){
    std::cout << "foo(const std::optional<dataType>& bar)" << std::endl;
    if(bar == std::nullopt)
        return {};
    return foo(*bar);
}

#ifdef ENABLE_AFTER
#ifdef CONST_REF_FUNCTION
// Causes infinite recursion
std::vector<dataTypeReturn> foo(const dataType& bar){
#else
std::vector<dataTypeReturn> foo(dataType& bar){
#endif
std::vector<dataTypeReturn> foo(const dataType& bar){
    std::cout << "foo(const dataType& bar)" << std::endl;
    return std::vector<dataTypeReturn>(10, dataTypeReturn{});
}
#endif

class Wrapper{
    public:
        std::vector<dataTypeReturn> foo(const std::optional<dataType>& bar){
            std::cout << "foo(const std::optional<dataType>& bar)" << std::endl;
            if(bar == std::nullopt)
                return {};
            return foo(*bar);
        }
    private:
#ifdef CONST_REF_CLASS
        // Causes expected behavior
        std::vector<dataTypeReturn> foo(const dataType& bar){
#else
        // Causes infinite recursion
        std::vector<dataTypeReturn> foo(dataType& bar){
#endif
            std::cout << "foo(const dataType& bar)" << std::endl;
            return std::vector<dataTypeReturn>(10, dataTypeReturn{});
        }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    std::optional<dataType> myoptional(dataType{});
    foo(myoptional);

    Wrapper mywrapper;
    mywrapper.foo(myoptional);
    return 0;
}
```

1. In the case of the global functions, why depending on where I define the function the recursion happens or not? What would be the compile-process to decide what function to call?
2. In both cases, marking the parameter as const reference for the function that receives the underlying type of the optional does not incurr in the recursion, why? I was looking at the constructor implementations of `std::optional` and the only that could match I think is `template < class U = value_type > constexpr optional( U&& value );` but I don't see how `*bar` ends up as a rvalue-ref.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are dereferencing a `const optional<datatype>`, you are using `const value_type & optional::operator*() const`, not `value_type & optional::operator*()`.

A free function definition only looks at names declared preceding it. This is one of the reasons for having declarations of functions in headers. In the case of a member function, definitions of members see all the declarations of members.

`foo(dataType& bar)` is not a viable overload. If you haven't declared `foo(const dataType& bar)` *before* the definition of `foo(const optional<dataType>& bar)`, the only viable overload is `foo(const optional<dataType>& bar)`, which constructs a temporary optional. It deduces `U` as `const dataType &`, and `const dataType & &&` is [collapsed](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference) to `const dataType &`

Comment: Got it, for free functions is all clear. The only thing that I didn't understand is, why in the member functions I have to declare `foo(const dataType& bar)` and not `foo(dataType& bar)`. The former has the expected behavior and the latter incurs infinite recursion.

Comment: in both `foo(*bar)`, you are using `const value_type & optional::operator*() const`, not `value_type & optional::operator*()`